# Hacer ECHO en PHP con saltos de línea (Datos desde una BD)

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Estoy almacenando el texto de un `textarea` en mi **base de datos**, y en esta puedo ver cómo se almacena el texto respetando los saltos de línea existentes.

El problema es que a la hora de recoger estos datos con PHP e imprimirlos dentro de una etiqueta `<p>`, **no se muestran los saltos de línea**, sino que todo está junto.

Comment: Conviene que resuelvas esto de una forma concienzuda. Creo que aquí la clave es saber cómo estás guardando los datos en la base de datos, o más bien **cómo conviene guardarlos** (si con saltos del tipo `\n`, o con etiquetas HTML). Según los contextos donde vayas a usar los datos debes tomar la decisión adecuada. Luego podrás adaptar lo que haga falta al momento de mostrar esos datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al recibir el texto que tienes en el textarea, el texto se guarda de forma literal; es decir, no se guardan etiquetas `<br/>` ni `<p>`. Por lo que cuando has guardado el texto, los saltos de línea se han guardado con el caracter `\n`.

Cuando escribes en pantalla el texto, los saltos de línea (`\n`) en HTML se muestran como espacios; por eso todo el texto te sale todo junto. Para evitar que esto te pase, tendrás que reemplazar los saltos de línea por elementos `<br/>`. Esto lo puedes hacer fácilmente así:

```
<?php echo nl2br($contenidoTextArea); ?>
```

La función `nl2br` inserta saltos de línea HTML antes de todas las nuevas líneas que se encuentre en un string. Más información:

- https://www.php.net/nl2br